# Insert dummy multiple X rows between groups with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

HI suppose I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("group_1","group_2","group_3", "group_4", "group_5", "group_6"), each=3),
                 X = paste(letters[1:18]),
                 Y = c(1:18))

 df
     group X  Y
1  group_1 a  1
2  group_1 b  2
3  group_1 c  3
4  group_2 d  4
5  group_2 e  5
6  group_2 f  6
7  group_3 g  7
8  group_3 h  8
9  group_3 i  9
10 group_4 j 10
11 group_4 k 11
12 group_4 l 12
13 group_5 m 13
14 group_5 n 14
15 group_5 o 15
16 group_6 p 16
17 group_6 q 17
18 group_6 r 18
```

What I want is to insert 5 rows with values of -10 in the Y columns but retain the group id

I tried doing this based on a similar cross post but cannot seem to retain group id and this only seem to work to insert 1 row.

```
> df %>%
+   group_split(group) %>% 
+   map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
+             add_row(Y = -10, .after = 0))
# A tibble: 24 x 3
   group   X         Y
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
 1 NA      NA      -10
 2 group_1 a         1
 3 group_1 b         2
 4 group_1 c         3
 5 NA      NA      -10
 6 group_2 d         4
 7 group_2 e         5
 8 group_2 f         6
 9 NA      NA      -10
```

the example above fails because it only inserts 1 row moreover the group id is loss, ideally for example, there should be 5 rows with group_1 inserted with the Y values of -10.

is this possible? thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a doubt.  Did you meant to insert 5 rows per each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the group ID, I suggest `group_modify`. First, a helper function to add a blank row to a group

```
add_blank <- function(x, n=5) {
  tibble::add_row(x, X=rep(NA, n), Y=rep(-10, n))
}
```

And then you can do

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_modify(~add_blank(., 5))
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Out of curiosity is there a way to add the rows before rather than after?

Comment: The add_row function has options for before and after. Check out the `?add_row` help page.

Answer (score 2):

We could add `uncount` after the `add_row` to replicate the first row 5 times

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
   group_split(group) %>% 
   map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
                add_row(group = first(.x$group), Y = -10, .after = 0) %>%
                uncount(rep(c(5, 1), c(1, n()-1))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 48 x 3
#   group   X         Y
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 2 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 3 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 4 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 5 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 6 group_1 a         1
# 7 group_1 b         2
# 8 group_1 c         3
# 9 group_2 <NA>    -10
#10 group_2 <NA>    -10
# … with 38 more rows
```

---

Or as the number of columns are only 3, we could also do this in `dplyr` alone with `summarise` after grouping by the 'group'.  In the newer versions of `dplyr`, `summarise` doesn't have the constraint to return a single row per group

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(X = c(rep(NA_character_, 5), X), 
              Y = c(rep(-10, 5), Y), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 48 x 3
#   group   X         Y
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 2 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 3 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 4 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 5 group_1 <NA>    -10
# 6 group_1 a         1
# 7 group_1 b         2
# 8 group_1 c         3
# 9 group_2 <NA>    -10
#10 group_2 <NA>    -10
# … with 38 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `split` + `rbind`

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    lapply(
      split(df, df$group),
      function(x) {
        rbind(setNames(data.frame(NA, NA, -10), names(x)), x)
      }
    )
  )
)
```

gives

```
     group    X   Y
1     <NA> <NA> -10
2  group_1    a   1
3  group_1    b   2
4  group_1    c   3
5     <NA> <NA> -10
6  group_2    d   4
7  group_2    e   5
8  group_2    f   6
9     <NA> <NA> -10
10 group_3    g   7
11 group_3    h   8
12 group_3    i   9
13    <NA> <NA> -10
14 group_4    j  10
15 group_4    k  11
16 group_4    l  12
17    <NA> <NA> -10
18 group_5    m  13
19 group_5    n  14
20 group_5    o  15
21    <NA> <NA> -10
22 group_6    p  16
23 group_6    q  17
24 group_6    r  18
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you look for this solution?

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do({ df <- . 
  last_row           <- df %>% slice(n())
  last_row$Y  <- -10
  df                 <- bind_rows(df, last_row)
  })
```

Output:

```
   group   X         Y
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
 1 group_1 a         1
 2 group_1 b         2
 3 group_1 c         3
 4 group_1 c       -10
 5 group_2 d         4
 6 group_2 e         5
 7 group_2 f         6
 8 group_2 f       -10
 9 group_3 g         7
10 group_3 h         8
11 group_3 i         9
12 group_3 i       -10
13 group_4 j        10
14 group_4 k        11
15 group_4 l        12
16 group_4 l       -10
17 group_5 m        13
18 group_5 n        14
19 group_5 o        15
20 group_5 o       -10
21 group_6 p        16
22 group_6 q        17
23 group_6 r        18
24 group_6 r       -10
```

Answer (score 1):

For each group you can add 5 dummy rows and bind to the original `df`.

Base R option :

```
result <- rbind(df, data.frame(group = rep(unique(df$group), each = 5), X = NA, Y = -10))
result <- result[order(result$group), ]
rownames(result) <- NULL
result

#     group    X   Y
#1  group_1    a   1
#2  group_1    b   2
#3  group_1    c   3
#4  group_1 <NA> -10
#5  group_1 <NA> -10
#6  group_1 <NA> -10
#7  group_1 <NA> -10
#8  group_1 <NA> -10
#9  group_2    d   4
#10 group_2    e   5
#11 group_2    f   6
#12 group_2 <NA> -10
#13 group_2 <NA> -10
#...
```